# Get a fixed number of items from a generator

Tags: python, generator

What is the most efficient way to get a fixed number of items from a generator?

What I currently do is using `zip` and `range`. In this example I take
chunks of size 3 from the generator.

```
def f():
  x = 0
  while x < 21:
    yield x
    x += 1

g = f()

while True:
  x = [i for _, i in zip(range(3), g)]
  if not x:
    break
  print x
```

The background is that the database I use provides a generator object for query results. Than I fill a fixed size numpy array with data and process it as one batch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools

for elem in itertools.islice(f(), 3):
    print elem
```

and directly into your numpy array:

```
my_arr = np.array(itertools.islice(f(), 3))
```